# Can we have *.stackexchange.com aliases for sites that have their own domain names?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, redirection

I have a Chrome search engine of the form `https://%s.stackexchange.com/` that I use to quickly move between various SE sites (I find this more efficient than bumbling my way through the multicollider).

It would be nice if we could get aliases (like e.g. `https://so.stackexchange.com/` or `https://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com/` as a redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/) for all the sites that have their own domain names. I believe that's just the Trilogy (SO, pt/ja/ru.SO, SU, SF) and Stack Apps (plus corresponding metas where they exist, plus Meta MathOverflow).

Note that Ubuntu already has https://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/ redirecting to https://askubuntu.com/.

EDIT: Either I forgot to check MathOverflow when I originally posted this, or it's been added since then - https://mathoverflow.stackexchange.com/ redirects to https://mathoverflow.net/ now. However, https://mathoverflow.meta.stackexchange.com/ does not go anywhere.

Comment: FWIW you could hack this for yourself at the DNS level.

Comment: @djechlin By modifying the HOSTS file, right? I guess that's a reasonable workaround that I hadn't thought of, thanks.

Comment: I don't think you could just get around this with just DNS/HOSTS changes; you'd need to configure a server to serve the redirect. The Stack Exchange servers just throw up an error page for unknown domains of any sort. Stack Overflow doesn't have a unique IP you could point to. (edit: example [config](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cYcUK.png) and [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9MdoI.png))

Comment: Mmmm, careful hacking the hosts file for this, we do have multiple data centers - so you probably want to avoid using the IPs directly.

Comment: I can't fix this with a userscript, should I learn NodeJS? Oh wait, I can fix this with a userscript. In any case, however, client-side fixes won't help Google serve from domains that are outside the real SE domain. Oh wait, maybe I can tell Google to.

Comment: That's true, SO does error out on unknown domains.  You can't even get a valid response from [http://www.stackoverflow.com./](http://www.stackoverflow.com./).

Comment: @snailplane I think that's just because you put a period after the `.com`. `http://www.stackoverflow.com/` works fine.

Comment: @senshin Yes, that was my point :-)

Comment: @snailplane Oh, right, `.` is the global root domain name, isn't it? My bad, carry on. :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should Stack Exchanges sites with top-level domains have \*.stackexchange.com redirects?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73434/should-stack-exchanges-sites-with-top-level-domains-have-stackexchange-com-red)

Comment: @tchrist I just voted to close in the other direction since I think my writeup here is better than the other question.

Comment: You’re right, it is.  It doesn’t have their answer though.

Comment: shouldn't the meta.mathoverflow missing dns entry not be a seperate bug instead of hidden in this feature request? Seeing the answers on the other question I don't expect it gets fixed but it separates the different cases more clearly.

Comment: To add to the list of sites: http://arqade.com redirects to http://gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Robotnik True, but that's not quite germane here - this post is mainly interested with redirects from SE domains to non-SE domains (since it's only in cases where those redirects are absent that `http://%s.stackexchange.com/` fails). There are a number of other instances of non-SE domains redirecting to SE domains, including http://seasonedadvice.com/, http://askdifferent.com/, http://miyodeya.com/, and so forth.